# Change default width of images in graphicx package

Tags: graphics, scaling

Is it possible to change the default width of an image included via `\includegraphics` (from the `graphicx` package) to a custom value, for example `\linewidth`.

So I want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft,width=\linewidth]{graphicx}

%or something like \setglobalimagewidth=\linewidth

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{test1} %width=\linewidth
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{test1} %width=4cm


\end{document}
```

Comment: Another example, were this makes perfectly sense is the use of vector graphics, which do not suffer from scaling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some options of package `graphicx` can be set using `\setkeys`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \includegraphics{test1}
\end{document}
```

What is `Gin` ? Documentation:

> Here ‘Gin’ is the name used for the `keyval` keys associated with ‘Graphics inclusion`.

Comment: @Ciprian Tomoiagă Useful edit.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that I have the perfect solution but I am happy with:

```
% Define new length
\newlength{\myFigureStandardWidth}
% Set the new length to a specific value
\setlength{\myFigureStandardWidth}{0.90\textwidth}
```

When I insert a figure then I just use something like

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\myFigureStandardWidth]%
    {FigureName.png}%
\caption[Short Caption]{Long Caption}
\label{fig:FigureName}
\end{figure}
```

I am writing my phd thesis this way and have inserted over 50 figures this way.