# Autocomplete paths in \newcommand

Tags: editors, overleaf, auto-completion

I have defined a few custom commands using `\newcommand` in order to standardize figure sizes in a paper I am writing. For instance:

```
\newcommand{\bigfigure}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{#1}}
```

However when using this command I don't get the handy autocomplete of the path to the image as I would when just using `\includegraphics[]{...}`. Is there anyway I can enable this feature for my custom commands?

I am using Overleaf as my editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should contact the Overleaf support for this. LaTeX can do nothing with the auto-complete feature of editors.

Comment: The autocompletion is not something LaTeX (or TeX) does. It is entirely controlled by your editor (Overleaf in this case as combined IDE/TeX system). Usually editors have a hard-coded list of commands that get a 'special' treatment such as having their argument auto-completed as a file name.

Comment: *Very* relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/479076/35864. It seems that at present you can't customise Overleaf's autocomplete, so there is nothing you can do here.

Comment: _(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf)_ Just to confirm that indeed this isn't possible at the moment e.g. saying something like `\bigfigure` should have the same autocomplete behavior of `\includegraphics`, sorry!

Comment: @LianTzeLim Do you want to write an answer here, or is the question sufficiently similar to be closed as a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: @moewe I think it's similar i.e. autocompletion isn't customisable...

Comment: @LianTzeLim OK, voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Instead of this workaround with the new command, you could simply change the default size if figures: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79971/change-default-width-of-images-in-graphicx-package/79974#79974